# Making Buttons Do Different Things

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this code...

It works, but not how I want it to.

```js
$('.yesOrNo').on('click', function() {
  var $yes = $("#yes").on('click');
  var $no = $("#no").on('click');
  if ($yes) {
    $("#atSize").show();
    $("#ADA").hide();
  } else if ($no) {
    $("#anSize").show();
    $("#ADA").hide();
  }
});
```

What I want to do, is make it so if someone clicks yes, they get directed to HTML form A, and if they click No, they get directed to HTML form B

Comment: Show your html.

Comment: Please also provide the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to check for ID in the condition.

```
$('.yesOrNo').on('click' , function(){
    var $yes = $(this).attr('id') === 'yes';
var $no = $(this).attr('id') === 'no';

if($yes){
$("#atSize").show();
    $("#ADA").hide();
}
if($no){
$("#anSize").show();
    $("#ADA").hide();
}
});
```

If there's really only two choices - this can be simplified to:

```
    $('.yesOrNo').on('click' , function(){
        var $isYes = $(this).attr('id') === 'yes';

    if($isYes){
    $("#atSize").show();
        $("#ADA").hide();
    } else {
 $("#anSize").show();
        $("#ADA").hide();
}
    });
```

Another way of doing it:

```
    $('.yesOrNo').on('click' , function(){
var bool = $(this).attr('id') === 'yes';
var elToHide = bool ? '#atSize' : '#ADA';
var elToShow = bool ? '#ADA' : '#atSize';
$(elToHide).hide();
$(elToShow).show();
    });
```

Comment: var $yes = $(this).attr('id') === 'yes';
var $no = $(this).attr('id') === 'no';

Can you explain what those do?

Comment: I mean, they're not the best way to do it - but they check to see if the button clicked is the yes or no buttons. By Id.

Comment: I understand what this does, but what would be a better way of doing it?

Comment: I added a third that sets your hide and show elements dynamically and then just does the action.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```js
function yes(){ ... }
function no(){ ... }

var state = true;

$('.yesOrNo').on('click' , function(){
    if(state){
        yes();
        state = false;
    } else {
        no();
        state = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: for the functions, would I have to add onclick tags in html?

Comment: Nope, you only have to set the initial state true or false depening if you want to start with Yes() or No(), and obivously you have to put the logic for Yes and No in the appropriate function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.yesOrNo').on('click' , function(e){
    var choice = $(this).prop("id");

  if (choice=="yes") {
    $("#atSize").show();
    $("#ADA").hide();
  }
  else{
    $("#anSize").show();
    $("#ADA").hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: So just to learn from your code. The .prop("id"); , would I have to replace the id with my own id tags for yes and no?

Comment: No. prop("id") will receive the id of the element clicked. The structure can be just 

<p class="yesOrNo" id="yes">Yes</p><p class="yesOrNo" id="no">No</p>

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. You just blew my mind!

Answer (score 0):

You can do use `toggle` and `this.id`, like this:

```
$('#yes, #no').on('click' , function(e){
    $("#atSize").toggle(this.id == 'yes');
    $("#ADA").toggle(this.id !== 'yes');
});
```

```js
$('#yes, #no').on('click' , function(e){
    $("#atSize").toggle(this.id == 'yes');
    $("#ADA").toggle(this.id !== 'yes');
}).trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="yes">Yes</button>
<button id="no">No</button>
<form id="atSize">
  atSize: <input>
</form>
<form id="ADA">
  ADA: <input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a function for that, it's called `confirm()`

You can try this:

```
$('.yesOrNo').on('click', function() {
  if(confirm()){
    $("#atSize").show();
  }
  else{
    $("#anSize").show();
  }
  $("#ADA").hide();
});
```